# Why is bitmap parameter invalid?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, bitmap

trying to return a greyscaled version of the original image and pass it back to the picturebox. any thoughts?

here's the link I've uploaded:
http://prntscr.com/35mgj8

thx

Comment: Please post your code here (not sure your screenshot will still be here in a few years when someone may be interested in this post)

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet you are [constructing a bitmap image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we6s1x3.aspx) as the resource inside a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx). This will cause the returned image to be disposed.